# How to pass command line options to .mxml file when compiling using mxmlc?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, command-line, command-line-arguments, mxmlc

I've a batch script which is used to build my flex project. This script sets all the necessary info required to build the project. In this script .mxml file is compiled using mxmlc.I want to add an argument which can be then read by .mxml file. This argument will be used to make runtime decisions.

Any idea on how this can be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The term you're looking for is called **conditional compilation**.
There's no point in describing how it works here, since it's pretty well covered in the Adobe [docs on the subject](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7abd.html).